# Elegant way to create List<>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using this LINQ to Entity:

```
var t1 = (from cn in contracts
          join cl in client on cn.Id equals cl.Id
          join so in siteObject on cn.Id equals so.ContractId
          select new
          {
              siteObjId = so.Id,
              clientId = cl.Id,
          }).ToList();
```

t1 have this list:

[image]

Is there any elegant way using (for example LINQ) to create from the list above (t1), new list like that:

[image]

Comment: I think you're after a `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `group by` operator:

```
(from x in t1
 group x b x.ClientId into g
 select new
 {
     ClientId = g.Key,
     ModelIds = g.ToList()
 }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `group by` statement the items. For each item of result, you could concat the result group using [`string.Join(separator, collection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a result like `1,2,3`. But, first, given you are using Linq To Entities, first, try to execute a simple query grouping values. For sample:

```
var groupResult =  (from cn in contracts
                   join cl in client on cn.Id equals cl.Id
                   join so in siteObject on cn.Id equals so.ContractId
                   group cl by cl.Id into g
                   select new {
                        ClientId = g.Key,
                        Result = g
                   }).ToList();
```

And use Linq To Objects with the `groupResult` list, to join the values into a string, for sample:

```
var t1=  (from item in groupResult 
          select new {
               clientId = item.ClientId,
               siteObjId = string.Join(",", item.ToList()),
          });
```

Comment: Sorry, it was about the column you want to group, for sample: `clientId` in your case.

Comment: it very elegant way but, above answer it has alot errors.Can you check it please?

Comment: I get this exception:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join[Int32](System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You are using `Linq To Entities`, in other words, the linq does not know how to transform `string.Join` method in `sql` statment. I will change my anwser.

Comment: thanks but  now i have this error:

Error 10 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)